# A noun-adj to describe a product that is produced from a process that generates a lot of pollution

Tags: word-request

I would like to find a noun-adj to describe a product that is produced from a pollutive process, during which a lot of pollutants will be generated. The usage of the product will not generate any pollution.

> The government should not import __ products so as to reduce its off-shored pollution.

A. pollution-contained?
B. pollutive
C. pollution-bearing?
D. ...

Answer (score 1):

"Pollutive by-products" would probably best describe the pollutants created from a product manufacturing process. We could turn this into a phrase that fits the blank such as "pollutive by-product causing products," but it would be a bit wordy and sound unnatural. It may be better to reword the sentence to use an adjective clause like:

> The government should not import products **that cause pollutive by-products** so as to reduce its off-shored pollution.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you so much for your answer. Actually, yours is similar to what I am currently using, which is "products that are from pollutive industries". If there is no other way around, then I will adopt yours.

Comment: @gotube [Not so fast! (When should I accept an answer?)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/9161) I think it's a little soon to be suggesting that Elizabeth accept an answer.